# Is it possible render immutable my current browsing webpage and save all modifications to iterate over it back and forth?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, web

I am a the moment working on an old spaghetti website on which I would like to know what happens when I click on something.

The code really isn't clear, and I really struggle understanding what is happening.

Is there a way to prevent any modification to a webpage I'm currently viewing, save them for later, iterate from one state to another, and maybe see what functions / event altered the page between two states ?

An example would be :

- I click on a link
- a timeout finishes
- a deffered ends

that triggers

- x function
- page change to another url
- infinite loop
- whatever

Nothing appends to my page until i "click " "next state" (or "previous state")

and then I can see what has happen (diff of the two states)

Comment: As far as I understand from your question, you want to prevent anchor link from loading new page when it was clicked? If so, you should use 'event.preventDefault()' or simply return 'false' to your even handler here click event. Please read here https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: its been a long work day, i think i will reformulate haha

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if any current browsers support maintaining state between every single action that takes place.  However, you *can* get a finer grained control over when you pause after certain ambiguous action using varying breakpoints exposed to you by the browser you are using.

For example, you can add breakpoints in you JavaScript source which is all well and good, but in Chrome and Firefox, you can also add breakpoints to other things such as when a DOM element is removed or added, or when an XHR request is fired.  With that, you can get a slightly better handle on what code triggered the DOM change or any other event as apposed to setting a random breakpoint where you *think* something is about to happen and then having to step into and out of function after function trying to find the relevant code.

Chrome's documentation on how to use its varying breakpoints can be found here: [Pause Your Code With Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints)

Firefox's documentation is here: [Firefox Developer Tools - Debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger)